# Temporary failure resolving 'mirrors.aliyun.com' error after set static ip in /etc/netplan/0...yaml

Tags: networking, 20.04

I have a vm in vmware player, after changing `dhcp4:ture` into

```
 dhcp4: no
        addresses:
            - 192.168.134.127/24
        gateway4: 192.168.134.1
        nameservers:
            addresses: [127.0.0.53,192.168.134.1, 8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1]
```

in  `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml`

the ip is set seccessfully, but it seems that the server can not visit the internet anymore.

I get `Temporary failure resolving 'mirrors.aliyun.com'` .
Seems that I have trouble in DNS.
How can it be fixed?

---

update the output of `sudo netplan --debug apply`:

```
    root@server1:/home/hzg# netplan --debug apply
** (generate:1305968): DEBUG: 13:18:39.135: Processing input file /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml..
** (generate:1305968): DEBUG: 13:18:39.136: starting new processing pass
** (generate:1305968): DEBUG: 13:18:39.137: We have some netdefs, pass them through a final round of validation
** (generate:1305968): DEBUG: 13:18:39.137: ens33: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:1305968): DEBUG: 13:18:39.137: Configuration is valid
** (generate:1305968): DEBUG: 13:18:39.138: Generating output files..
** (generate:1305968): DEBUG: 13:18:39.139: openvswitch: definition ens33 is not for us (backend 1)
** (generate:1305968): DEBUG: 13:18:39.139: NetworkManager: definition ens33 is not for us (backend 1)
(generate:1305968): GLib-DEBUG: 13:18:39.140: posix_spawn avoided (fd close requested) 
(generate:1305968): GLib-DEBUG: 13:18:39.142: posix_spawn avoided (fd close requested) 
DEBUG:netplan generated networkd configuration changed, restarting networkd
DEBUG:ens33 not found in {}
DEBUG:Merged config:
network:
  ethernets:
    ens33:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.134.127/24
      dhcp4: false
      gateway4: 192.168.134.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 192.168.134.1
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 1.1.1.1
  version: 2

DEBUG:no netplan generated NM configuration exists
DEBUG:ens33 not found in {}
DEBUG:Merged config:
network:
  ethernets:
    ens33:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.134.127/24
      dhcp4: false
      gateway4: 192.168.134.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 192.168.134.1
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 1.1.1.1
  version: 2

DEBUG:Link changes: {}
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for lo
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for ens33
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for docker0
DEBUG:ens33 not found in {}
DEBUG:Merged config:
network:
  ethernets:
    ens33:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.134.127/24
      dhcp4: false
      gateway4: 192.168.134.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 192.168.134.1
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 1.1.1.1
  version: 2
```

Comment: In nameserver addresses, please take out 127.0.0.53 and try again, please.

Comment: @chili555 thx, but it does not work.

Comment: Did you: `sudo netplan generate` followed by `sudo netplan apply`? Does this work? `ping -c3 8.8.8.8` And this? `ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com`

Comment: @chili555 I tried just now: sudo netplan generate followed by sudo netplan apply, Then both ping command you mentioned is not working. is `8.8.8.8` a google ip? In China google can not be reached without a VPN.

Comment: Why, then, do you list it as a nameserver in your netplan file??

Comment: I think these nameserver will be tried sequencely and if one nameserver is working there will be no problem.@chili555

Comment: @chili555 Iconfirmed that `8.8.8.8` can be reached by Ping, if I set dhcp4 to true. Sorry for that.

Comment: If you set netplan to DHCP, do both pings work as expected? What address do you get? `ip addr show` Is it in the 192.168.134.xx range?

Comment: @chili555 I am not using that PC, will double-confirm it later. But I remember that if I set to DHCP, both pings(without -c3 option) work as expected. And I got 192.168.134.xx range IP shown by ifconfig.

Comment: Please confirm and post back the result.

Comment: @chili555 if I set to DHCP, result of  `ip addr show` : 192.168.134.129/24. both ping -c3 can reach the target.

Comment: May we see your entire netplan yaml file here: http://paste.ubuntu.com Give us the link to your paste. Is the address you specified above, 192.168.134.127/24 outside of the DHCP pool in the router; that is, is it possible that it's in use elsewhere, on a phone, tablet or other PC in your network? What is the result of: `sudo netplan --debug apply` ?

Comment: @chili555 https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/PbffFyqzSW/   . For the output of `sudo netplan --debug apply` please see my updates in the original post.

Comment: There are several references to Network Manager above. Is it installed and running? `sudo service NetworkManager status` If it is, it is preferable to set your details in NM. Also, there are several instances of ens33 not found. Is your ethernet interface actually ens33? `ifconfig`

Comment: It seemsthat NM is not there: `root@server1:/home/hzg# sudo service NetworkManager status
Unit NetworkManager.service could not be found.
`

Comment: @chili555 It should be `ens33`, the output of `ifconfig`: `root@server1:/home/hzg# 

ens33: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.134.127  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.134.255
        inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe29:bd21  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0c:29:29:bd:21  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 195269  bytes 63478777 (63.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 248803  bytes 39529980 (39.5 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

`

Answer (score 0):

Netplan is quite specific about spacing and indentation. As well, your yaml file omits the renderer. I suggest that you edit your file to:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens33:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.134.127/24
      gateway4: 192.168.134.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.134.1, 8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1]
```

Source: /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/static.yaml

Follow with:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

Did you connect? Test:

```
ping -c3 8.8.8.8
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```